# How to clear Integrate internal memory?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, timing, caching

I noticed that when I call `Integrate` for the first time, on an integral that I know will take longer than the time limit I give it, it will abort for the first time, as expected when wrapped by `TimeConstrained`. But on the third try (not the second!), it will return the antiderivative very quickly within the same time limit.

This tells me that `Integrate` seems to be loading things or caching things each time it is called?

Is it possible to somehow start each call of `Integrate` fresh, as the first call, but without restarting the kernel?  Here is an MWE. Run the following from a fresh kernel:

```
res = AbsoluteTiming[ TimeConstrained[Integrate[
       (Sqrt[1 - x]*x*(1 + x)^(2/3))/(-((1 - x)^(5/6)*(1 + x)^(1/3)) +
         (1 - x)^(2/3)*Sqrt[1 + x]), x], 500 $TimeUnit]]
```

Here is a screen shot

[image: Mathematica graphics]

An interesting thing is that I needed 3 calls to get an answer.  You might have to adjust the multiplier on `$TimeUnits` on your PC. For me, `500` seems to work just right for this illustration.

Using 11.1 on Windows 7, 64 bit.

I am trying to get predictable results each time, and would like the next integral calls not to be affected by the previous integral calls made in terms of timing.

Comment: Have you tried `ClearSystemCache["Symbolic"]`?

Comment: @J.M. Thanks! I did not know about this function. I just tried it and it seems to do the trick! I need to read more about this function.

Comment: Related: [(1115)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1115/121), [(91816)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/91816/121), [(135781)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/135781/121)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In general, whenever you suspect that *Mathematica*'s internal caching is affecting your results, it is a good idea to run `ClearSystemCache[]` first. If more specificity is necessary, one can try `ClearSystemCache["Numeric"]` for numeric computations, or `ClearSystemCache["Symbolic"]` for symbolic computations.

For more control of how caching is done for various objects, you can look at `SystemOptions["CacheOptions"]`. In particular, you can set `SetSystemOptions["CacheOptions" -> {"Symbolic" -> {"Cache" -> False}}]` if you want no caching of symbolic results during your entire session.